# exists/not exists without referring to outer table

Tags: sql, exists, activiti, not-exists

I am working on Activiti framework. This is a workflow automation framework  in java. I have following query:

```
select RES.* from ACT_RU_TASK RES where exists 
(select 1 from ACT_RU_IDENTITYLINK I where not exists
   (
    select 1 from ACT_RU_VARIABLE A0 where RES.ID_ = A0.TASK_ID_ and A0.NAME_= 'excludedUserForTask'
    and A0.TYPE_ = 'string' and A0.TEXT_ ='my_id'
   )
   and I.TASK_ID_ = RES.ID_ and I.TYPE_ = 'candidate' and I.GROUP_ID_ IN ('my_skill_1')
)
and 
RES.ASSIGNEE_ is null order by RES.priority_ desc ,RES.create_time_ LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

So, my objective is to fetch all the tasks(from table ACT_RU_TASK) which are not yet assigned(RES.ASSIGNEE_ is null), and which are not assignable to this user('my_id'), and need skill 'my_skill_1'. In activiti,ACT_RU_IDENTITYLINK table contains the link between a task and a skill(GROUP_ID_), and ACT_RU_VARIABLE contains information on variables associated to a task(here we ensure that variable 'excludedUserForTask' and 'my_id' are not paired).

But problem I face is that apart from tasks which need skill 'my_skill_1', I get other tasks too which need other skills.

Looking at the query, I am not sure about this part:

```
   select 1 from ACT_RU_IDENTITYLINK I where not exists
   (
    select 1 from ACT_RU_VARIABLE A0 where RES.ID_ = A0.TASK_ID_ and A0.NAME_= 'excludedUserForTask'
    and A0.TYPE_ = 'string' and A0.TEXT_ ='my_id'
   )
   and I.TASK_ID_ = RES.ID_ and I.TYPE_ = 'candidate' and I.GROUP_ID_ IN ('my_skill_1')
```

In subquery for NOT EXISTS, we are not referring to ACT_RU_IDENTITYLINK. Does exist/not exist work this way? I think we need to refer outer table(ACT_RU_IDENTITYLINK) too in subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `not exists` part has to be part of the outer query condition like this

```
select RES.* 
from ACT_RU_TASK RES 
where exists 
    (
        select 1 
        from ACT_RU_IDENTITYLINK I 
            and I.TASK_ID_ = RES.ID_ 
            and I.TYPE_ = 'candidate' 
            and I.GROUP_ID_ IN ('my_skill_1')
    ) 
    and not exists
    (
        select 1 
        from ACT_RU_VARIABLE A0 
        where RES.ID_ = A0.TASK_ID_ 
          and A0.NAME_= 'excludedUserForTask'
          and A0.TYPE_ = 'string' and A0.TEXT_ ='my_id'
    )
    and RES.ASSIGNEE_ is null 
order by RES.priority_ desc ,RES.create_time_ 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```